# Whether RhinoMocks died?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

The last build was on 1/5/2010.

I'm going to learn a mock framework and I don't want to learn a product is going to die.

Comment: Rhino mocks is a framework that is used by lots of companies. But if you want something new check out http://code.google.com/p/moq/ Or in VS2012 you can just use fakes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rhino doesn't seem to be developed anymore. You can take a look at more up-to-date frameworks (last update date in brackets):

- (09.2011) [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)
- (08.2012) [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy)
- (08.2012) [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/)

Functionality-wise, they're all similar and choice which one to use is often a matter of syntax preference. Also note that, while not being developed, it's still possible to do majority of mocking/stubbing with Rhino; none of the newer frameworks offers something particularly important that you wouldn't be able to do with Rhino. It's just the code might be bit more complex.

<sub>According to [this poll](http://osherove.com/blog/2012/5/4/annual-poll-which-isolation-framework-do-you-use-if-any.html) by Roy Osherove, Moq seems to be most popular of the 3 (as of May 2012). However, it's FakeItEasy or NSubstitute that [are going to make it](http://osherove.com/blog/2012/6/26/fakeiteasy-or-nsubstitute-which-should-i-use-for-samples-in.html) to the second edition of Roy's unit testing book.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

**Rhino Mocks is not more developed – but noteworthy, it was resurrected for about a year**. [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/blog), an author of Rhino Mocks is not developing it anymore and after two years of being inactive, the project development lead has been taken by [Mike Meisinger](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/).

You can track current Rhino Mocks progress and its new features at Mike Meisinger blog under [Rhino-Mocks](https://meisinger2.wordpress.com/category/rhino-mocks/) category.

You may look at reactivated Rhino Mocks at:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/meisinger/rhino-mocks/)
- [NuGet (Rhino Mocks 3.6.1) [latest stable]](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RhinoMocks/)
- [NuGet (Rhino Mocks 4.0.0-alpha3)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RhinoMocks/4.0.0-alpha3)

Read more at:

- (2013-05-08) **Ayende: [The state of Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/blog/161826/the-state-of-rhino-mocks)**
- (2013-05-16) Meisinger: [State of Rhino Mocks](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/state-of-rhino-mocks/)
- (2013-05-19) **Meisinger: [Rhino Mocks New Home](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/rhino-mocks-new-home/)**
- (2013-05-22) Ayende: [Rhino Mocks' future](http://ayende.com/blog/162241/rhino-mocks-future)
- (2013-05-28) Meisinger: [Planning the Next Rhino Mock](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/planning-the-next-rhino-mock/)
- (2014-03-31) Meisinger: [Rhino Mocks 4.0.0 Alpha Released](https://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/rhino-mocks-4-0-0-alpha-released/)

Comment: *sigh* It'd be nice to get one final Rhino 4.0.0-stable release.